# how to configure hard memory limit for builds in drone.io

Tags: drone.io

Perhaps I am missing it, but I see no method to control the the hard memory limit for any given build (I have builds being murdered because of it). Is the build memory limit based on the build params supplied by the client (this means a single client can bring down everything) or is there someplace I can configure the service to only allow 512mb (for example) per build?

Answer (score 3):

You can limit the max amount of memory per-container by setting the global `DRONE_LIMIT_MEM` variable (with the server). This should be set to the amount of memory in bytes, for example:

```
DRONE_LIMIT_MEM_SWAP=512000000
DRONE_LIMIT_MEM=512000000
```

These limits are passed to Docker when Drone starts a container [1]. It is the equivalent to the following Docker command:

```
docker run --memory=512000000 <image>
```

[1] https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/resource_constraints/#limit-a-containers-access-to-memory